# Changing char array with double reference in C

Tags: c, pointers

Why this works

```
char** p;
char* s = (char*)malloc(6);
strcpy(s,"abcde");
s[2] = 'f';
printf("%s",s);
*p = s;
p[0][2] = 'g';
printf("\n%s",*p);
```

Output:

```
abfde
abgde
```

But this doesn't

```
char** p;
char* s = (char*)malloc(6);
strcpy(s,"abcde");
s[2] = 'f';
printf("%s",s);
*p = s;
*p[2] = 'g';
printf("\n%s",*p);
```

Output:

```
abfde
abfde
```

Why accessing the location with index in first case (p[0][2]) works but not with the reference (*p[2]) ?

Comment: Given the posted code, what does `p` point to when you dereference it with `*p = s;`?

Comment: First, you're writing through an uninitialized pointer, `p`.  You need to initialize it to point to a valid `char *` before assigning to `*p`.  Second, `*p[2]` groups as `*(p[2])`, which is equivalent to `p[2][0]`.  You could use `(*p)[2]` to achieve the intended effect.

Answer (score 3):

The first code has undefined behavior, `p` is uninitialized when `*p = s;` happens. Therefore, it doesn't "work"; anything could happen.

That said, look into operator precedence rules.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding to the previous comments.

Instead of:

```
*p = s;
```

Do this to properly initialize `p`:

```
p = &s;
```

Finally, all it takes is to use parenthesis in order to obtain the same effect as `p[0][2]`:

```
(*p)[2] = 'g';
```